# network-manager not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, network-manager

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 in Dell inspiron n5010, my network manager disabling wifi is not working. It was fine in Ubuntu 12.04. I need help.

Comment: reinstall. `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove network-manager && sudo apt-get install network-manager`

Answer (score 2):

Try running this in the terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinstalling, do this in the command line :

```
sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 txpower off
```

OR

```
sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 txpower on
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate a little always what this commands do to make it clear to OP and others :)